# JavaVM on shared linux web server (JustHost)

Tags: java, linux, jvm, webserver

I have just bought a shell access addon to my website and tried to run a java based program, but no good.

I looked into it and found that I needed JavaVM but I cant find one for linux shared web servers. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download and unpack the JRE from java.com on the shared host.

Most probably you will not have root access, so you will have to install it on your own home directory.

Instructions are here:

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#selfextracting

Comment: damn! my host doesn't allow java in any form, i'm going to godaddy

Comment: Thats common, running a JVM takes away 100 -400M of RAM. Shared hosts cant afford that. You would probably need a host that would allow you to host a Java Web App. Even those hosts usually share a VM for multiple customers.